# How to work with Experimental`NumericalFunction?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, mathematical-optimization, undocumented, fundamentals

This question is intimately connected with previous one: "[How to create internally optimized expression for computing with high WorkingPrecision?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25432/280)"

[Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) correctly states in [the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25432/how-to-create-internally-optimized-expression-for-computing-with-high-workingpre#comment78937_25432):

> A good answer will hopefully discuss the
>   `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``, which is a structure produced by
>   `FindMinimum` from the function and its `Jacobian` that is optimized
>   for fast numerical evaluation. I know almost nothing about these
>   objects or how to create/use them, but I would like to find out.

From [other questions on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NumericalFunction) it is apparent that other built-in numerical functions also use `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` which seems to be the standard way to optimize numerical evaluation. It is not documented but it is placed in the `Experimental` context which ["contains functions that are being considered for official inclusion in future versions of *Mathematica*"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Experimental/guide/ExperimentalPackage.html). This undocumented function is of crucial importance because currently it is **the only way to optimize *arbitrary precision* calculations**. For `MachinePrecision` we have `Compile` but nothing documented for arbitrary precision. How to work with `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``?

Comment: One way to collect such objects for examination is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41512/12).  It might be useful to have a temporary community wiki answer where people can share findings before a final answer is developed.

Comment: Example: ``f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, {Sin[x + y], x^2 y}, {2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]``.  Usage: `f[{2, 3}]`.  See also `f["Properties"]` and `Options[Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction]`.  I don't really know how to take advantage of them.  On small examples like `f` they do not appear to be more efficient.

Comment: Have you seen [NDSolveStateData, §``NDSolve`StateData`` Properties](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#93858351)?  It has ways of getting a `NumericalFunction` from diff. eqs.

Answer (score 39):

To create `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``, one needs to evaluate `` Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[vars, expr, dims] `` where `vars` is a list of arguments, `expr` - the expression from which the numerical function will be created, `dims` - the dimensions of the output matrix produced by this expression. If the output is scalar, then `dims` should be set to `{}`.

**It also accepts an optional fourth argument**, a list of input types corresponding to `vars`, such as `{_Real, _Real}`, as can be seen in [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/a586cab2025cd53d7a7ac8be32c269d7b6f8abbf/Misc/ArrayOfFunctionsRule.m) that creates a new `NIntegrate` rule. If the fourth argument is not specified, the resulting function expects a single argument: a list of the `vars` values. If the fourth argument is specified, the resulting function expects a sequence of arguments instead of a single list.

The `` Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction `` has several options, including `WorkingPrecision`, `EvaluationMonitor`, `StepMonitor`, `Compiled`, `Hessian`, `Gradient` and `Jacobian` which work in the same way [as in `FindMinimum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSpecifyingDerivatives.html).

`Hessian`, `Gradient` and `Jacobian` can be `Automatic` (the default), `Symbolic` or `FiniteDifference`. According to the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#1128081347),

> One of the things that `NumericalFunction` does is to handle derivatives
> automatically. By default, symbolic derivatives are used if they can
> be found, and otherwise finite differences are used.

I tried to use the `"Sparse"` suboption of `Hessian` and found that it is ignored. **It also has interesting options `"ErrorReturn"`, `"SampleArgument"` and `Message`** the purpose of which is unclear to me.

---

The created `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` has several properties:

```
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, {Sin[x + y], x^2 y}, {2}];
f["Properties"]
```

> ```
> {"ArgumentDimensions", "ArgumentNames", "ArgumentUnits", "CompiledFunction", 
> "FunctionExpression", "InputIndexes", "InputTypes", "Properties", "ResultUnits", 
> "SolutionDataComponents", "WorkingPrecision"}
> ```

The most useful is that you can directly compute Gradient/Jacobian or Hessian for `expr` for any numerical values of parameters:

```
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, {Sin[x + y], x^2 y}, {2}];

f["Hessian"[{1, 2}]]
f["Gradient"[{1, 2}]]
f["Jacobian"[{1, 2}]]
```

> ```
> {{{-0.14112,-0.14112},{-0.14112,-0.14112}},{{4.,2.},{2.,0.}}}
> {{-0.989992,-0.989992},{4.,1.}}
> {{-0.989992,-0.989992},{4.,1.}}
> ```

When called for the first time, symbolic Hessian or Jacobian will be created (if the corresponding parameter is set to `Automatic` or `Symbolic`), further evaluation will be executed MUCH faster. For `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` `Gradient` and `Jacobian` options seem to do the same.

There also is `` NDSolve`ValidNumericalFunctionQ `` which seemingly tests whether the created `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` is valid.

There also are some useful `Message`s for `` Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction `` defined in the file "Messages.m".

---

Another mentionable feature of `NumericalFunction` is its first argument isn't necessarily a list of `Symbol`:

```
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{Subscript[x, 1], y}, {Sin[Subscript[x, 1] + y],
     Subscript[x, 1]^2 y}, {2}];
f[{2, 3}]   
(* {-0.958924, 12.} *)
```

---

Another striking feature of `NumericalFunction` is it penetrates the barrier of `_?NumericQ`. Consider the following sample:

```
Clear[f, r]
expr = Sin[r]; f[r_?NumericQ] := expr
```

Clearly this definition of `f` is improper. Code like `f[1]` won't evaluate to `Sin[1]`:

```
f[1]
(* Sin[r] *)
```

But it's not the case if a `NumericalFunction` is created for `f`!:

```
func = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{r}, f[r], {}];

func[{1}]
(* 0.841471 *)
```

This seems to explain why `NMaximize`/`NMinimize` can handle improper black-box function:

```
NMinimize[f[r], r]
(* {-1., {r -> -1.5708}} *)

NMaximize[f[r], r]
(* {1., {r -> 1.5708}} *)
   
Trace[NMinimize[f[r], r], _Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction, 
    TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union // First
(* HoldForm[
 Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{r}, 
  f[r], {}, {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Compiled -> Automatic}]] *)

Trace[NMaximize[f[r], r], _Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction, 
    TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union // First
(* HoldForm[
 Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{r}, -f[r], {}, {WorkingPrecision -> 
    MachinePrecision, Compiled -> Automatic}]] *)
```

Comment: I have tested it a little in the way described in the [linked question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25432/280) and found almost no speedup for `MachinePrecision` calculations in the simplest case I work with and more than 8x speedup in more involved cases (although the results are not identical to an ordinary function).

Comment: Maybe you can help OP [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42952/5478)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a little addition related to the performance of `NumericalFunction`.

Suppose we have a function like

```
func = Cos[x + y^2] Sin[x^2 - y];
```

A `NumericalFunction` may be created as follows.  The first variant `nf0[{x0, y0}]` returns a scalar. The second variant `nf1[{x0, y0}]` returns a 1-vector `{z0}` for a given input `{x0, y0}`, and the reason for including it will be seen in the timing of the `"Hessian"` further down.

```
nf0 = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, func, {}];
nf1 = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, {func}, {1}];
```

For a `NumericalFunction` `nf`, `nf["Jacobian"@{x, y}]` and `nf["Jacobian"@{x, y}]` compute the Jacobian and Hessian, respectively.  I thought to explore how efficient these were compared to the symbolic `D[func, {{x, y}}]` and `D[func, {{x, y}, 2}]`.

The Hessian of `func` above turns out to be fairly complicated.  I thought to use `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` to improve its speed for the sake of comparison.  This was done as follows:

```
hf1 = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[
    Simplify@D[func, {{x, y}, 2}]] /. 
   Experimental`OptimizedExpression[f_] :> 
    Function @@ Hold[{x, y}, f];
```

It's possible to optimize `func` and its Jacobian expression, too, which I did mainly because I was making a table.

I also include compiled versions and vectorized ones.  Functions were compiled with a simple `Compile[{x, y}, expr]`.  I wasn't trying to find the absolute fastest method of evaluating, just giving some basis for evaluating the performance of `NumericalFunction`.  Vectorization was done on the `y` coordinate as follows, using both the plain and optimized expressions for the function, Jacobian, and Hessian:

```
Do[testf[x, Range[0., 4., dx]], {x, 0., 4., dx}] // RepeatedTiming
```

The other functions were timed as follows:

```
Do[testf[x, y], {x, 0., 4., dx}, {y, 0., 4., dx}] // RepeatedTiming
```

Unsurprisingly, the results show that the vectorized optimized form is fast and usually fastest.  The `NumericalFunction` is faster than the symbolic expression when evaluated on single inputs.  The most surprising outcome is the difference between the performances of the scalar `nf0` and the vector `nf1` on the Hessian.  The vector form evaluates at least twice as fast as the scalar form.  They seem computationally equivalent to me. If either is more expensive, I would think it would be the `First` of the vector form `nf1`, which in fact is the case when evaluating the function and Jacobian.  The same difference in speed is observed if `func` is changed to the simpler `x^2 y^3`.

| `dx = 1./8` | `dx = 1./128` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |