# NIntegrate-ing a compiled function

Tags: numerical-integration, compile

I'm trying to integrate numerically in 6 dimensions a very long expression and I read about the option to `NIntegrate` a compiled function which should be faster. However, this is not the case. I have tried a simple example with just 3 variables.

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x]^2 y Exp[z];
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, g[x, y, z]];
f2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := f[x, y, z];
```

And now the integrals and the output:

```
NIntegrate[f2[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}]//Timing
```

> ```
> {2.335434,2.03437*10^7}
> ```

```
NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}]//Timing
```

> ```
> {0.316207,2.03437*10^7}
> ```

Can I do anything to improve the speed of the integral of the compiled function?

Comment: Define `f2 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, Sin[x]^2*y*Exp[z] 1, RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]` and it helps a bit. But I suspect the rest of it comes from `NIntegrate`'s symbolic preprocessing, which cannot be done for a purely numeric function.

Comment: I omitted the 1 at the end, if it is a typo - please, revisit the post accordingly

Comment: @OleksandrR. Your comment suggests that we need a version of `NIntegrate` that would use a symbolic function for preprocessing, and its compiled version to calculate numerical values of the integrand. I tried to build something like this using constructs like `bva2D2sub2ci[k_, bv_, p_, \[Psi]_] :=
  If[NumericQ[bv] && NumericQ[p] && NumericQ[\[Psi]],...` but at best achieved the same speed as when using an uncompiled integrand.

Answer (score 6):

No fair, you let `NIntegrate` see the symbolic form of the native expression.  If you do the same trick:

```
     f3[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := g[x, y, z];


 NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}] // Timing  
 NIntegrate[f2[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}] // Timing
 NIntegrate[f3[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}] // Timing
```

> { 0.513922, 1.77873, 2.30465}

You see the compiled version ( `f2` ) is indeed marginally faster than the numeric-only-uncompiled  version ( `f3` ).

If you count the function evaluations for the three cases like this:

```
 Length@Last@Last@Reap@
     NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9},
          EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[0]]
```

for the three cases you get:

> 1354, 134673, 134673

you see the speed of the first case comes from `NIntegrate` being smart about the quadrature scheme, not the actual performance of the function.

Comment: I took the OP's question to be about integrating a black-box compiled function versus the symbolic one.  It's not about the speed of compiled functions per se.  So I think it's "fair."  On the other hand, your second point is important. That's sort of what I was alluding to in my first point, but you state it (and support it) much more elegantly. (+1)

Comment: Actually the speed comparison depends heavily on the upper integration limits. For example change the upper `x` limit from `100` to `20` then the compiled version is faster. So compiling the target function might be benefitial unless MMA has a smart way to treat the integration. But it is certainly worth a try for specific applications.

Comment: Indeed if you set `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` in the numerical integration then the compiled version will always be equally fast.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some reasons or surmises:

1. I believe some functions are special-cased in `NIntegrate`; I'm pretty sure this is true for low-degree polynomials.
2. To get the advantage of compiling, use
   `f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, Evaluate@g[x, y, z]]`, but it will still be slower than just using `g`.  Without the `Evaluate`, the compiled function makes an external call to the uncompiled `g`.  (Inspect with `` Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]; CompilePrint[f] ``.)
3. I think another reason is that `NIntegrate` does arithmetic with extra precision by constructing an [`` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43513/how-to-work-with-experimentalnumericalfunction).  But `NIntegrate` does not do this in the case of the compiled function, and it *may* be costing time by converting results to higher precision or some other sort of numerical fiddling around.

Example

```
f2tr = Trace[
   NIntegrate[f2[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}],
   _Experimental`NumericalFunction,
   TraceInternal -> True];

gtr = Trace[
   NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}],
   _Experimental`NumericalFunction,
   TraceInternal -> True];

f2tr
(*
  {}
*)

Length@Flatten[gtr]
First@Flatten[gtr]
(*
  12537
  Experimental`NumericalFunction[{x,y,z},E^z y Sin[x]^2,"-NumericalFunctionData-"]
*)
```

Comment: Your first observation is correct, because `NIntegrate` uses by default the [Gauss-Kronrod integration rule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) for one dimensional integrals.

Answer (score 4):

With `RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False` and `Evaluate` you don't need an intermediate function and get 3x speedup:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, g[x, y, z]];
f2[x_Real, y_Real, z_Real] := f[x, y, z];
f3 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, 
   Evaluate@g[x, y, z], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False];
Timing@NIntegrate[f2[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}]
Timing@NIntegrate[f3[x, y, z], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 9}]
```

> ```
> {2.74562, 2.03437*10^7}
> {0.904806, 2.03437*10^7}
> ```