# Numerical optimization yields strange result with imaginary number

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, evaluation

**Edit**: I changed the range for $r$ to $d/s \leq r \leq 1/2$ from the original one, $0 \leq r \leq 1/2$ and now it works! But there has emerged another issue, which is presented below.

Consider the following function:
$$V=f(i(r),r;q,c,d,s)$$
That is, $V$ is a function of $i$ and $r$ with parameters $q$, $c$, $d$, $s$, and $i$ is a function of $r$. So ultimately it narrows down to $V$ as a function of $r$ along with the parameters. Given certain parameter values, I would like to numerically find $r$ that maximizes $V$ under the condition for the range of $r$ as $d/s \leq r \leq 1/2$.

Here is the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = 0.8; d = 0.8; q = 1.5; s = 4;
i = -0.1875` + 0.3125` r + (-10.5625` + (391.875` - 401.5625` r) r)/(-2197.` + r (-31335.` + (75825.` - 48125.` r) r) + 320.` \[Sqrt](r (6591.` + r (-193686.` + r (2.76172`*^6 + r (-7.51875`*^6 + (7.511625`*^6 - 2.5675`*^6 r) r))))))^(1/3) - 0.0625` (-2197.` + r (-31335.` + (75825.` - 48125.` r) r) + 320.` \[Sqrt](r (6591.` + r (-193686.` + r (2.76172`*^6 + r (-7.51875`*^6 + (7.511625`*^6 -2.5675`*^6 r) r))))))^(1/3);
v = (1 - r) y + r x;
V[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[If[v - d (1 + i) > 0, v - d (1 + i), 0]/s^2, {x, 0, (d (1 + i))/r}, {y, (d (1 + i))/(1 - r) - r/(1 - r) x, s}] + NIntegrate[If[v - d (1 + i) > 0, v - d (1 + i), 0]/s^2, {x, (d (1 + i))/r, s}, {y, 0, s}]
NMaximize[{V[r], d/s <= r <= 1/2}, r]
```

which produces `{1.13693, {r -> 0.40297}}` as expected.

But to confirm the solution, when I evaluate `V[]` at the optimal `r`:

```
V[0.40297]
```

I get an error as follows:

[image]

Why this??

Comment: Start by using `Piecewise` instead of `If` in your function definition.

Comment: The parentheses in your new `i` isn't balanced, please double check it. Also, please notice that, though your first trial accidentally succeeds, it's not proper, try the following and think about what's wrong: `aaa=2 b; f[b_]:=aaa; f[343]`.

Comment: @xzczd, I corrected the second `i` and it is now balanced. Thanks. Regarding my first trial, I think I'm getting what's wrong with your simple example, but not quite sure how it sheds light on what's wrong with my code. Can you please help?

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, it's improper, but it happens to work in this case. (To see why it's improper, try e.g. `V[1/4]` outside of `NMaximize`. ) As to the imaginary number, try `i /. r -> 0.02`.

Comment: Your "i" yields imaginary numbers. Try: `i /. r -> 0.01`what gives `-0.908448 + 0.565341 I`

Comment: @xzczd, I made the following change: `d/s <= r <= 1/2`. So, `r -> 0.02` can be ignored, right? But there is another issue; please see (1) in the post: not only `V[1/4]` but also `V[]` evaluated at the optimal `r` shows that it is improper. Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielHuber, @xzczd, I made the following change: `d/s <= r <= 1/2`. So, `r -> 0.01` can be ignored, right? But there is another issue; please see (1) in the post: when `V[]` is evaluated at the optimal `r`, I get an error message. Do you know why?

Comment: Let me repeat:  try the following and think about what's wrong: `aaa=2 b; f[b_]:=aaa; f[343]`

Comment: @xzczd, yes I understand what's wrong in your example. But I couldn't figure out which part of my `V[]` function exhibits a similar error. Can you please enlighten me? But your point is that the `V` function is supposed to yield errors in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my comments above, your definition for `V` is improper, your first success is just an accident. To be more specific, `b` in `aaa` is amount to the `r` in `i` and `v`. Perhaps I should ask in another way: how will you fix the code `aaa=2 b; f[b_]:=aaa; f[343]` to make it output `686`?

Comment: @xzczd, with the lower bound for `r` set correctly, now even the new `i` works! Do you know how this success is related to your example? But to confirm the output solution, when I evaluate `V[]` at the optimal `r`, I get an error message as shown in the post. Do you know why? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accident in OP's code is interesting enough, so let me write an answer.

First let me explain why `V[0.40297]` "doesn't work". The issue can be boiled down to the following:

> Why doesn't
>
> ```
> aaa = 2 b; 
> f[b_] := aaa; 
> f[343]
> ```
>
> output `686`? How to fix this sample?

Well actually I've written a [Chinese tutorial](http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=a9c14381c11b44ad47980c44c200d529) elaborating this issue and have been thinking about translating it to English for years but I'm just too lazy to do it. In short, `f[343]` doesn't evaluate to `686` because the `2 b` in `aaa` isn't **explicitly** there when the function `f` is defined, so it's not **noticed**. The most basic fix for this issue is to define `aaa` as a function of `b` to make the `b` in `aaa` explicit:

```
Clear[aaa, b, f]
aaa[b_] = 2 b;
f[b_] := aaa[b];
f[343]
(* 686 *)
```

And your `V` can be fixed in exactly the same manner i.e. make the `r` in `i` and `v` explicit:

```
Clear[i, v, r, x, y];
c = 0.8; d = 0.8; q = 1.5; s = 4;
i[r_] = -0.1875` + 
   0.3125` r + (-10.5625` + (391.875` - 401.5625` r)  r)/(-2197.` + 
      r  (-31335.` + (75825.` - 48125.` r)  r) + 
      320.`  √(r  (6591.` + 
            r (-193686.` + 
               r (2.76172`*^6 + 
                  r (-7.51875`*^6 + (7.511625`*^6 - 2.5675`*^6 r) r))))))^(1/3) - 
   0.0625`  (-2197.` + r  (-31335.` + (75825.` - 48125.` r)  r) + 
      320.`  √(r  (6591.` + 
            r (-193686.` + 
               r (2.76172`*^6 + 
                  r (-7.51875`*^6 + (7.511625`*^6 - 2.5675`*^6 r) r))))))^(1/3);
v[r_] = (1 - r) y + r x;
V[r_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{v = v[r], i = i[r]}, 
  NIntegrate[If[v - d (1 + i) > 0, v - d (1 + i), 0]/
    s^2, {x, 0, (d (1 + i))/r}, {y, (d (1 + i))/(1 - r) - (r x)/(1 - r), s}] + 
   NIntegrate[If[v - d (1 + i) > 0, v - d (1 + i), 0]/
    s^2, {x, (d (1 + i))/r, s}, {y, 0, s}]]
```

This isn't the only fix, of course. For example, the original `i` and `v` can be used if we control the evaluation order a bit:

```
(* The following is for the original v and i *)
(V[r_?NumericQ] := 
    With[{v = #, i = #2}, 
     NIntegrate[
       If[v - d  (1 + i) > 0, v - d  (1 + i), 0]/s^2, {x, 
        0, (d  (1 + i))/r}, {y, (d  (1 + i))/(1 - r) - (r  x)/(1 - r), s}] + 
      NIntegrate[
       If[v - d  (1 + i) > 0, v - d  (1 + i), 0]/s^2, {x, (d  (1 + i))/r, s}, {y, 0, 
        s}]]) &[v, i]
```

"OK, then why does the improper `V` in original code happen to work?" As mentioned above, this accident is the interesting part of this question, and it seems to be an issue that's never discussed in this site before! For better illustration, I'll again use a toy example:

```
Clear[f, r]

expr = 2 r^2; f[r_?NumericQ] := expr

NMinimize[f[r], r]
(* {2.79991*10^-17, {r -> -3.7416*10^-9}} *)
```

Clearly, `f` isn't proper, but `NMinimize` still manages to "work". What's happening here? The reason seems to be, an `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` has been created internally:

```
Trace[NMinimize[f[r], r], _Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction, 
    TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union // First
(* HoldForm[Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{r}, f[r], {}, 
     {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Compiled -> Automatic}]] *)
```

And `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` owns a really striking feature: it penetrates the black-box function defined with `_?NumericQ`!:

```
tst = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{r}, f[r], {}];
tst[{3}]
(* 18. *)
```

I've added this to [this community wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/1871).

### Remark

It's reasonable to guess `NMinimize` has essentially called `Block` to penetrate the `_?NumericQ`. Indeed, `Block` is mentioned in document of numeric functions like `NIntegrate`, etc.:

> `NIntegrate` has attribute `HoldAll` and effectively uses `Block` to localize variables.
> `FindMinimum` has attribute `HoldAll`, and effectively uses `Block` to localize variables.

But since `Trace[NMinimize[f[r], r], _Block, TraceInternal -> True]` doesn't find anything related, this is merely a guess.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much!