# Evaluation control of nested With, If and Integrate

Tags: evaluation, core-language, scoping, conditional

Can you explain the behaviour of the following?

The first `With` outputs unevaluated `If`.

So in the second `With` I added `Evaluate` before `If` but then still variable `a` is unevaluated.

So in third `With` I added `Evaluate` even before `Integrate` and the output is correct `1/2`.

But then in the fourth `With` I added `Print` at each branch of `If` which should not affect evaluation in any way yet the output is miraculously `a/2`, i.e. variable `a` is not evaluated again.

How to make it work even with the prints?

```
Clear[int, cond, a]
int = a x;
cond = a > 0;

With[{a = 1}, 
 If[cond, Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]

With[{a = 1}, 
 Evaluate@If[cond, Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], 
   Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]

With[{a = 1}, 
 Evaluate@If[cond, Evaluate@Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], 
   Evaluate@Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]

With[{a = 1}, 
 Evaluate@If[cond, Print["First possibility:"]; 
   Evaluate@Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Print["Second possibility:"]; 
   Evaluate@Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numerical optimization yields strange result with imaginary number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296435/numerical-optimization-yields-strange-result-with-imaginary-number)

Comment: (1) I think you will learn the most if you look at the evaluation process yourself by using [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)! (2) You have to wrap the whole thing inside `With` with `Evaluate` (`Evaluate[e1; e2]`), not each separate statement (`Evaluate@e1; Evaluate@e2;`) to overcome the fact that `With` is [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). Otherwise, `Evaluate` doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: @xzczd There is no reference to `Print` and that it should affect the evaluation process.

Comment: …Please notice `;` is also a function `CompoundExpression`. When `Evaluate` is inside the `CompoundExpression`, it no longer breaks through `HoldRest` attribute of `If`.

Comment: @three777, evaluation process in Mathematica can be tricky at the beginning; I suggest reading [Evaluation of Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html). In your case, you are dealing with two functions that are holding their arguments, namely `With` and `If`! That is why you need to escape both of them by two separate `Evaluate`s: `With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[If[cond, Evaluate[Print["First possibility:"]; Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}]], Evaluate[Print["Second possibility:"]; Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]]]`

Comment: But again: I really suggest you closely inspect the output of `Trace` for your cases! :) It will help you understand better what is going on.

Comment: @Domen Have you tried? Your last code prints miraculously both `"First possibility:"` and `"Second possibility:"`. Which is nonsense.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to use `Evaluate` in last case, I'm just explaining **why** your last trial fails.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, please don't substantially alter the question in the OP's name. You edit is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Domen I just wanted to point out that your suggestion solves one problem but introduces another maybe even more serious one. I do not understand why you canceled my edit since it made the question more clear. You seem to miss that the `Print` plays a substantial  role here not just `With` and `If`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a second thought I retract my vote for duplicate because the relevance is probably not so obvious at least for beginners, but do remember this post is essentially duplicate of the following:

[Numerical optimization yields strange result with imaginary number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/296435/1871)

[Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/1871)

In short:

1. `a`s in `int` and `cond` are not **explicit** i.e. they *hide inside* `int` and `cond` so `With` cannot *see* them.
2. `Evaluate` is a function that *breaks through* evaluation control of `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, `HoldRest`, etc. but as mentioned in the document of `Evaluate`: "`Evaluate` only overrides `HoldFirst` etc. attributes when it appears **directly** as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held."
3. `With` and `If` both have attribute for evaluation control. `With` has `HoldAll`, `If` has `HoldRest`.
4. Code like `Print["First possibility:"]; Evaluate@Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}]` won't work in `If`, because `;` is also a function whose `FullForm` is `CompoundExpression`, so the `Evaluate` won't break through the evaluation control of `If`.

Here're 3 possible fixes for your last `With[…]`, in order of increasing difficulty for digesting：

```
Clear[int, cond, a]
int[a_] = a  x;
cond[a_] = a > 0;

With[{a = 1}, 
 With[{cond = cond[a], int = int[a]}, If[cond, Print["First possibility:"];
   Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Print["Second possibility:"];
   Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]]

Clear[int, cond, a]
int = a  x;
cond = a > 0;

With[{a = 1}, If[#, Print["First possibility:"];
    Integrate[#2, {x, 0, a}], Print["Second possibility:"];
    Integrate[#2, {x, -a, 0}]]] &[cond, int]

Clear[int, cond, a]
int = a  x;
cond = a > 0;

Unevaluated@With[{a = 1}, If[cond, Print["First possibility:"];
    Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Print["Second possibility:"];
    Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]] /. Flatten[OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{cond, int}]
```

Comment: I like the second variant which is concise and easy to read although I do not understand why this should work just because arguments are taken from outside of `With`.

Comment: @three777 It's just a more targeted evaluation control. If a function doesn't have attribute like `HoldAll`, its argument(s) will evaluate before **going into** the function. (Remember `&` is just shorthand for `Function`. )

Answer (score 4):

Evaluation process in Mathematica can be tricky at the beginning; I suggest reading the tutorial on the [Evaluation of Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html).

The problem you are facing is that both `With` and `If` hold their arguments (`With` is [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), and `If` is [`HoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html)). In order to circumvent this, you can wrap the argument with [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html).

Let's begin with simpler examples:

```
cond = a > 0;
With[{a = 1}, cond]
(* a > 0 *)
```

Why did `With` not change the value of `a`? Because, roughly speaking, `With` replaces only symbols it can lexically explicitly "see"! But it only sees `cond`, because the evaluation of `cond` to `a > 0` is postponed due to `HoldAll`. If you cirvument this, `cond` is evaluated before `With` does its magic:

```
With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[cond]]
(* True *)
```

You can more closely inspect all of this by using [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).

```
With[{a = 1}, cond] // Trace
(* {With[{a=1}, cond], cond, a>0} *)

With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[cond]] // Trace
(* {{cond, a>0}, With[{a=1},a>0], 1>0, True} *)
```

See the difference?

Now to adding `If`:

```
int = a x;

With[{a = 1}, If[cond, int]]
(* If[a>0,int] *)
With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[If[cond, int]]]
(* a x *)
```

The first output is expected: `With` didn't see any `a` to be replaced, so the output is an undecided `If`. But what's with the second output? Look at the `Trace`:

```
With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[If[cond, int]]] // Trace
(* {{{cond,a>0},If[a>0,int]},With[{a=1},If[a>0,int]],If[1>0,int],
    {1>0,True},If[True,int],int,a x} *)
```

Because `If` holds its arguments (except the first one), they get evaluated only after `With` has done the replacement! So you have to now also circumvent this holding inside `If` with another `Evaluate`:

```
With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[If[cond, Evaluate[int]]]]
(* x *)
```

Now let's add `Print`s:

```
With[{a = 1}, 
 Evaluate[
  If[cond, 
     Evaluate[Print["1st"]; int], 
     Evaluate[Print["2nd"]; int]
]]]
(* 1st *)
(* 2nd *)
(* x *)
```

Whoops? Why did this happen? Well, this is exactly the reason why `If` holds its arguments! You do *not* want to evaluate both branches before you now which one is the correct one! However, by using `Evaluate`, we evaluated both of them, so both `Print`s occurred. What can you do now? Well, many different options:

1. Ugly nested `With`s

```
With[{a = 1}, Evaluate[With[{int = int}, If[cond, Print["1st"]; int, Print["2nd"]; int]]]]
(* 1st *)
(* x *)
```

2. or more elegantly, define `int` and `cond` as functions

```
Clear[cond, int];
cond[a_] := a > 0;
int[a_] := ax;

With[{a = 1}, If[cond[a], Print["1st"]; int[a], Print["2nd"]; int[a]]]
(* 1st *)
(* x *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the game, but I feel like there is some pedagogical value to be added.

Let's start with the basic setup:

```
int = a x;
cond = a > 0;
With[{a = 1}, If[cond, Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]
(* result was the unsimplified If that you didn't want *)
```

What was the purpose of setting up the situation this way? What were you hoping to achieve? My guess is that you wanted to extract out repeated chunks of code or chunks that maybe you wanted easier control over (the `int` and `cond`). Then, you wanted to sort of "parameterize" the situation (the `a=1`). If that's correct, then you simply chose the wrong "localizing" construct. What `With` does is to replace symbols that appear explicitly in the body. It's just a simple lexical operation. But what you wanted was to temporarily give a value to a "global" symbol. The construct for that is `Block`:

```
int = a  x;
cond = a > 0;
Block[{a = 1}, If[cond, Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]
(* 1/2 *)
```

Now, as several responses have indicated, you also could have "functionalized" your situation rather than relying on "global variables" and side-effects. I won't reiterate those.

There is a case for using `With`, and that's when you want a sort of purely side-effect free little "experiment" (for lack of a better word). It might be easiest to see by building it up bit by bit:

```
(* starting expression where everything is explicit *)
If[a > 0, Integrate[a*x, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[a*x, {x, -a, 0}]]

(* choose something to abstract out, maybe the a *)
With[{a = 1}, If[a > 0, Integrate[a*x, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[a*x, {x, -a, 0}]]]

(* choose another thing to abstract, but respect the dependency by nesting the With *)
With[
  {a = 1},
  With[{cond = a > 0}, If[cond, Integrate[a*x, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[a*x, {x, -a, 0}]]]]

(* repeat *)
With[
  {a = 1},
  With[
    {cond = a > 0, int = a*x}, 
    If[cond, Integrate[int, {x, 0, a}], Integrate[int, {x, -a, 0}]]]]
```

Every step in this transformation "worked"--you could have stopped (or continued on) whenever you wanted. Also, the symbols `a`, `int`, and `cond` are now not polluting your "global namespace", which reduces the risk of side-effects and name collisions. You also have a nice little setup where you can easily change the value of `a`, `cond`, or `int` independently to see what happens.