# NDSolve with integrated event, discrete variable and arbitrary-precision arithmetic gives error

Tags: numerical-integration, event-detection, arbitrary-precision, version-13.3

I'm trying to solve an ODE numerically with `NDSolve` but get an unexpected error message (`` Experimental`NumericalFunction::nlnum1 ``), and the domain of the returned solution is empty. I get this error whenever I simultaneously have an event with `"IntegrateEvent" -> True`, a discrete variable and am using arbitrary-precision arithmetic (e.g. `WorkingPrecision -> 30`).

Minimal example (version: 13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)):

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1, , "IntegrateEvent" -> True]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* Experimental`NumericalFunction: The function value <<1>> is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2}
   when the arguments are {0,{0,-1.`30.},{1.`30.}}.*)
```

If the event is not integrated, `y` not discrete or the working precision `MachinePrecision`, the error goes away, i.e. all of the following return the expected solution (although I'm not sure why the last one does not give `NDSolve::underdet`).

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1, , "IntegrateEvent" -> False]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1, , "IntegrateEvent" -> True]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1, , "IntegrateEvent" -> True]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Is this a bug or can anyone understand what's going on?

**Update:**
The problem seems to be the `Abs`. The following also works as expected

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x[t] > 1, , "IntegrateEvent" -> True]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

(The `Abs` is easy to remove in this minimal example but not in the actual problem.)

Comment: This sort of error is discussed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/1063.  I would call it a bug.

Comment: Also, @Michael_E2 might have some advice.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks! I found the comment that `NumericalFunction` penetrates the barrier of `_?NumericQ` but no explicit discussion about ```Experimental`NumericalFunction::nlnum1``` through the link you sent. Do you think that's the problem here?