# Why does WhenEvent not work with DiscontinuitySignature and the Brent location method?

Tags: numerical-integration, event-detection, version-13.3

Why is it not possible to use `"LocationMethod" -> "Brent"` to locate an event when the action is `"DiscontinuitySignature"`? The following code produces `NDSolve::jevlm` (in version 13.3):

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1,
 WhenEvent[1 - x[t] == 0, y[t] -> "DiscontinuitySignature", "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}]
(* NDSolve: The location method "BrentBracketRoot" may only be used when
   the event can be handled as a real-valued function. *)
```

It seems like the `"DiscontinuitySignature"` action is important to reproduce the error. With another action, the code works as expected, for instance:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1,
 WhenEvent[1 - x[t] == 0, "StopIntegration", "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]},
 {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}, DiscreteVariables -> {y \[Element] {-1, 1}}]
```

**Context:** I have an application where I suspect that WhenEvent is not locating the event precisely enough, leading to imprecise results. To solve this, I tried `"LocationMethod" -> "Brent"` but then encountered the above problem. I have also tried `"IntegrateEvent" -> True` with [a different error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296687/ndsolve-with-integrated-event-discrete-variable-and-arbitrary-precision-arithme).

Comment: `"LocationMethod" -> "BrentBracketRoot"` seems to work fine (no error message). I think you will find an explanation in the tutorial on [Events and Discontinuities in Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html#19093): _For events that are set up to handle discontinuity crossings, it is very useful for the event handler to have a bracketing interval $t_{a-}<t_a<t_{a+}$ so that it can do proper evaluations on either side of the discontinuity and ensure the crossing is done correctly. This is done with the method "BrentBracketRoot"._

Comment: I don't understand the error since `"BrentBracketRoot"` is the default method chosen for `"DiscontinuitySignature"`. The event is removed from the system, so the error has serious consequences. Perhaps report it to WRI. As far the main goal to get `NDSolve` to try Brent's method, it seems it is done automatically.

Comment: Based on the comment by @Domen, it seems like the problem in the OP was indeed using `"LocationMethod" -> "Brent"` instead of `"LocationMethod" -> "BrentBracketRoot"` (I would be happy to accept it if you post it as an answer).

Comment: @Goofy, using `"LocationMethod" -> "BrentBracketRoot"` I get the same results as with no options, so it indeed seems like this is the default. (Unfortunately, it did not solve my underlying problem but that's off-topic.)